# (Why) is this Integer() cast 64 bit safe?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

This comes from a third party library (suited for 32 and 64 bits), so I'm assuming the Integer() cast is safe, but why? The `TDataModule` descendant is essentially a pointer, the `Variant` does not make it easier to understand...

```
type
  TROSession = 
  class
    private
    protected
      function GetValues(const Name: string): Variant; virtual;
      procedure SetValues(const Name: string; const Value: Variant); virtual;
    public
      property Values[const Name: string]: Variant read GetValues write SetValues; default;
  end;

procedure TDatamoduleServer.InMemorySessionManagerSessionCreated(const aSession: TROSession);
var
   LDataModuleDataBase: TDataModuleDataBase;  // a TDataModule descendant
begin
   LDataModuleDatabase := TDataModuleDataBase.Create(nil); 
   aSession.Values[SESSION_DMDATABASE] := Integer(LDataModuleDataBase);
```

Comment: If you ever use the `aSession.Values[SESSION_DMDATABASE]` value as an object pointer, this is a bug. It may work by accident most of the time, but it has never been safe in a 64-bit app. Now with the new ASLR settings, it will seldom work at all. Instead, you'll corrupt your memory, get AVs, etc. A huge amount of bugs of this kind have surfaced since the introduction of the new ASLR settings. (But if you only use `aSession.Values[SESSION_DMDATABASE]` as a not necessarily unique ID of the object, it maybe doesn't matter that you disregard half of the "digits".)

Comment: "I'm assuming the Integer() cast is safe". It's not safe.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I must say "ID (identification) that is not necessarily unique, i.e., doesn't uniquely identify something" *is* a bit of a stretch, isn't it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: "ID" was a poor choice of word, but I was hoping my point was clear anyway.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I don't think it was a poor choice of words – ID'ing the object was the intended purpose, my comment wasn't on your wording, but on how they failed at it.

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in RemObjects Data Abstract that nobody ever noticed ;)

Comment: @StefanGlienke It's not so bad, the Integer() cast was in *our* code. Changed everything to NativeUInt